# Angularjs http basic auth with username and password for Pivotal Tracker api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, pivotaltracker

I'm trying to develop an application to get the Pivotal Tracker stories. First of all I need to do basic authentication to get my Pivotal Tracker token.

Using PHP cURL, I'm doing like this,

```
curl -X GET --user vader:bad_word "https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me"
```

I want this to be done with Angular. I have tried,

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' + password);
```

but it shows,

```
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

any suggestions to get done?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivotal Tracker have not yet support client side username and password validation method. Currently they are supporting only X-Token method from client side. If we want to do this, we have to use server side scripting only.

check [here](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api#Browser_Example) : [validation can only be done with token and *not with "username/password"*](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api#Browser_Example)

and [generating the token should done in server side](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api#Authenticating_Using_API_Tokens).

> Each individual Pivotal Tracker login may be associated with a unique
>   API Token value, which serves as a ***single-factor authentication for
>   API requests***. API tokens are allocated and copied from an
>   individual's Profile page after logging into Tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also have sent mail to Pivotal Tracker and got the response.

Answer (score 0):

PivotalTracker obviously do not send down the correct CORS headers maybe? This would need to be in the http response header of the pre-flight HTTP OPTION call.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

You can see these links for more info:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

http://enable-cors.org/

http://community.pivotaltracker.com/pivotal/topics/cors_stopped_working_on_api_calls_today